# c# Crystal Report 2010 The type initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.ReportSourceFactory' threw an exception

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, crystal-reports-2010

Just Updated my desktop application from visual studio 2008 to visual studio 2010,
i.e framework 3.5 to framework 4.0

everything running fine but crystal report throwing some exception

`The type initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.ReportSourceFactory' threw an exception`

I have tried uninstalling and installing crystal reports setup for visual studio 2010,
uninstalled other version 10.8 for visual studio 2008,
still its showing same error,
Please Help

Comment: Is there any more details in the error?

Comment: no its only showing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i got my answer,

download latest update of crystal report for visual studio 2010 from sap. 
it will remove the error.